# Cryogenic liquid pressurization resulting in overpressurized tank

Tags: cryogenics, lox, pressure, tanks

I want to pressurize a cryogenic liquid (LN2 in this test. Eventually LOX).
I have a setup similar to this and follow a similar procedure to what is described, but I don’t see the same tank pressure behavior.
[image]

Instead, the curve looks like this, where “set pressure” is the pressure reading just after the pressurant regulator set to 700psi. T=12 is when the pressurization begins. T=40 is when expulsion begins.
[image]
A check valve is in place so no gas flows back into the pressurant bottle.
Notice how the tank pressure does not level-off at equilibrium at T=22. Tank pressure will continue to rise beyond, and I started expulsion before it could rise too high. It was observed previously that if I did not start expulsion it could rise past 1100psi.

Any idea what is going on? I am aware of “collapse factor” of pressurants for cryogens but the behavior should not be dissimilar from the first picture.

Comment: is your pressure relief valve working correctly?

Comment: I read half way before realizing this is not a hypothetical question! ;-)

Comment: Is this off topic? Cryogenics is related but it's not really a question about space exploration.

Comment: @GdD Not sure. On the other hand, this reads more like an engineering problem then Space Exploration, on the other hand there is a significant overlap between those topics. Might be appropriate to discuss this on Meta, not in comments, though.

Comment: The pressure in the "expected behavior" graph continues to rise as well. Exactly what differences are you asking about?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: I've no experience in cryogenics so I'm just grasping at nonsense here, but could there be an area of the tank which is not sufficiently insulated and is remaining warm?

Comment: @Hobbes the pressure relief valve is set to 1440psi.

Comment: @Polygnome please tell me if this question belongs in a different subdomain.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I see what you mean. I guess the difference is the rate of pressure increase. My data is showing a much faster rate of pressure increase/boil off (roughly 15PSI/sec versus the expected 1PSI/sec)

Comment: Those differences can be due to size and shape differences in the tanks, temperature of incoming pressurant, insulation of tanks, etc etc.